# How to exclude the namespace prefixes and rename the tags?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like this:

```
<n0:BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:L52:/1SAI/TAS31250ABB49732A386280:804">
<ProfileData>
<Data>ACD</Data>
</ProfileData>
</n0:BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest>
```

I want to remove this prefix and replace the tag BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest with  using xslt.

Expected Output:

```
<Profiles>
<ProfileData>
<Data>ACD</Data>
</ProfileData>
</Profiles>
```

Comment: Please share your initial XSLT and specify what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you could do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <Profiles>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ProfileData" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    </Profiles>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 1.0 you will need to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <Profiles>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ProfileData"/>
    </Profiles>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global"
    exclude-result-prefixes="n0"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="n0:BusinessPartnerSUITEBulkReplicateRequest">
    <Profiles>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ProfileData" copy-namespaces="no"/>
    </Profiles>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBG6

Comment: Your stylesheet says `version="1.0"` but `copy-namespaces` requires XSLT 2.0.